# pdfbox - unable to capture modified values from pdf

Tags: pdfbox

I have a requirement to open PDF on JXBrowser and let the user modify values on PDF and upon saving, I should able to read the modified values and save to database.

My issue was, I am unable to fetch modified values from pdf, its always sending back original values from pdf (acroForm.getField(field name);). Could you help me if there is any other way to solve this problem.

I am using pdfbox 2.0.1

Appreciate your help.

Thanks,
Prasad

Update1:
Adding sample code that I have used in my application

```
PDDocument PDFDoc = PDDocument.load(complaintform.pdf);

LoggerProvider.setLevel(Level.OFF);
Base64Encoder b64 = new Base64Encoder();
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
PDFDoc.save(baos);
String pdfHTML = "<HTML><BODY style=\"width:100%; height:100%\" > <embed  style=\"width:100%; height:100%\" src=\"data:application/pdf;base64,"+b64.encode(baos.toByteArray())+"\"type=\"application/pdf\"></BODY></HTML>";

Browser browser = new Browser();
BrowserView browserView = new BrowserView(browser);
this.add(browserView, BorderLayout.CENTER);
browser.loadHTML(pdfHTML);



save()
{
    PDDocumentCatalog docCatalog = PDFDoc.getDocumentCatalog();
    PDAcroForm acroForm = docCatalog.getAcroForm();
    PDField field = acroForm.getField("last");

    String modifiedValue = field.getValueAsString();
}
```

Comment: Have you checked whether the values in the saved document are changed at all?

Comment: Its not saving even after pddocument.save() call.

Comment: If possible, please share the PDF (upload it somewhere), and include more of the code you are using.

Comment: Your save() call is just saving into a stream what's in the complaintform.pdf file. Apparently, what you expected is that somehow, entering a field in a browser-displayed PDF would result in a modified pdf that could be retrieved by the server.

Comment: @prasad Seriously, the browser loads the PDF from a base64 URL. How do you expect changes made in the browser to appear in the Java objects initialized before all that?

Comment: @mkl Thanks for your reply. I am actually new to pdfbox, and just trying different options. Could you help me if there is any other way to fulfill my requirement. I am okay to use any option, all I want is to open pdf from java application and let user to modify data on pdf fields and at the end I need to fetch modified data and save it to database.  Appreciate if you could point me to some sample.

Comment: You could use a submit-form action. This is explained in page 451ff of the 32000 PDF specification. You'll have to implement stuff on the server too. However I've never seen this in real life. Websites just use ordinary HTML forms for input.